# Ruby on Rails mysql2 driver can't connect, mysql clients / telnet can

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I'm encountering an odd issue with the mysql2 gem. I have a Dreamhost VPS and a Dreamhost MySQL VPS. Going from the VPS to the MySQL VPS, the following database.yml works fine:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: [redacted]
  pool: 15
  username: [redacted]
  password: [redacted]
  host: mysql.medlapps.com
```

However, running `rails s -e=production` on my MacBook or the same code our new Limestone dedicated server results in a connection error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.7/lib/mysql2/client.rb:43:in `connect': Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.medlapps.com' (61) (Mysql2::Error)
```

The MySQL VPS is allowing connections outside the Dreamhost network. Using Liya (a Mac OS X MySQL GUI client) as well as `telnet mysql.medlapps.com 3306` both are able to connect with no issues. This is only an issue with the mysql2 gem, or configuration with it.

Edit: `mysql -h mysql.medlapps.com -u [redacted] -p[redacted]` also works on our new dedicated server. This leads me to believe it is an issue with the mysql2 driver / Rails or how they are configured.

Edit 2: Turns out this is not an issue with MySQL or mysql2 gem. Something else is failing to load on startup. Running a basic hello world Rails app works fine on our new dedicated box. However the issue we are having is that our website app fails to run in production mode. The server hangs and provides no errors. Will keep post updated when we figure out the issue.

Any thoughts / help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: hm, looks odd. Best guess i have is networking. See this (maybe it helps): http://www.rasyid.net/2007/07/31/error-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server/

Comment: Running mysql -h mysql.medlapps.com -u [redacted] -p[redacted] connects just fine on both my MacBook and our new dedicated server.

It clearly seems this is an issue with the mysql2 gem (or it's config) and how it's trying to connect.

Comment: Updated. Looks like this isn't an issue with mysql2 gem, but with the app itself. Something fails to load and nor Passenger / Rails provide any clues as to what. Server just hangs